# R: Can someone spot the error in my log transformation (multiple linear regression)?

Tags: r, logging, transformation

I have to finish the following by tomorrow but I am not getting the log transformation right (want to improve model fit). Maybe someone could take a look. Maybe hard since I can't post the whole doc here but maybe you notice an issue. Would appreciate it a lot!

```
lm_log.model() = lm(log1p(adr) ~ log1p(country) + log1p(hotel)+ log1p(arrival_date_month)+log1p(is_repeated_guest)+ log1p(previous_cancellations) + log1p(market_segment), 
                          data = dailyrateregnoo)
```

Comment: You say it is "not right".  In what way?  Are you getting an error message?  Are you getting a result but are for some reason unsatisfied with it?  What is wrong?

Comment: i think you have to provide an example. If I do this: `df <- data.frame(a1=c(1,2,3), a2=c(2,3,4), a3=c(3,4,5))` and `lm(log1p(a1)~log1p(a2)+log1p(a3), data=df)` I get no problems. Is your data table maybe not formatted correctly? If you provide an example it will be easier for everyone to help.

Comment: The code just doesn't execute it, so it stops. Is there a possibility to post a rmd file here?

Comment: @GiKo You might have suppressed the error or warning message. (Enable it to see those.) For Log transformation: 1. make sure you don't have any value equal to zero, as log(0) = -Inf. If you find such case, either remove it or add small value to it (like 0.00001).